# LINQ to SQL query with multiple contained strings

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Given an SQL table with a column of strings:

```
hello
what
do
doing
does
boing
she
```

and a list of substrings:

```
he
ing
```

I would like to create a LINQ query to get all the rows in the table that contain any of the strings in the list.

In the example above. the result should be:

```
hello
doing
boing
she
```

The query would look something like this, if a `ContainsAny` function existed and could be run on the SQL server:

```
table.where(x => x.column.ContainsAny(list))
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = data.Where(x => subStrings.Any(z => x.Contains(z))).ToList();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RlLsTI).